# Process has MainWindowHandle but not MainWindowTitle

Tags: c#

My process (p) is up and running (MFC GUI) and I am trying to retrieve its `MainWindowTitle` in C#.

```
Process p;
```

...

```
p.MainWindowTitle
```

returns empty ("").

but

```
p.MainWindowHandle
```

is not 0.

The process is right in front of me and I can see its name.
What can be the reason that the `MainWindowTitle` returns empty string?

Comment: Have you conformed that the window you're looking at actually is the main window, i.e. it's handle is the same as the value returned by `MainWindowHandle`?

Comment: This process has only 1 windows. But how can I confirm it anyway?

Comment: It only has one window that you can see but that doesn't necessarily mean that it only has one window.  You would use the same sort of tool that you use when working out the window hierarchy for API calls, e.g. Spy++.

Comment: OK I think I found the problem - very weird problem and I haven no idea how to solve it. You were right, the window handle I see while debugging, is not the correct handle I see in Spy++. The problem is that this handle (the process MainWindowHandle) belongs to a class named "TeamViewer_TitleBarButtonClass". As you probably understood, I have TeamViewer installed in my PC and every window has this kind of the Title Bar Button. So probably this Handle "Takes Over" the real MainHandle of the process. Sounds to me like a serious bug in Windows or TeamViewer.

Comment: I found another post with a similar problem, and the answer there was to uninstall TeamViewer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19135937/user32-getclassname-isnt-correct 
I can't do that, I can disable this title bar. But this is a bug.

Comment: Windows does not have a way for a program to say "this is my main window".  So Process.MainWindowHandle needs to use a heuristic, it simply assumes that the *first* window that was created by a program is the main one.  So sure, if you have a rogue program running that injects its own window(s) into other processes then you may well have a problem.  Particularly so if the process *does* create its own window first but then closes it again, like a login or splash window for example.  Count yourself lucky finding this problem now :)

Comment: So is there a better way to find the main window title? I can't count on finding these problems all the time

Comment: Wow! I can't say that I ever would have come up with uninstalling TeamViewer as a solution to a problem like that.  Just goes to show that there are all sorts of interactions going on in software that we never even think about until they bite us on the butt.

Comment: I didn't uninstall TeamViewer, just disabled the title bar button feature. But i totally agree with you.